# Wifi connection issues

Tags: java, android, android-wifi

I'm currently receiving the following errors in wifi communication:

Cannot refer to a non-final variable wifi inside an inner class defined in a different method

```
List<ScanResult> results = wifi.getScanResults();
```

Cannot be resolved to a variable

```
connectivity.setRadio(NetworkType.WIFI, false);
connectivity.setRadio(NetworkType.WIFI, true);
connectivity.setNetworkPreference(NetworkPreference.PREFER_WIFI);
int networkType = networkInfo.getType();
wifi.enableNetwork(netID, disableAllOtherstrue);
```

Thanks For any help in understanding these!!

Comment: it sames like you have a inner class, can you paste this part code?

Comment: either move wifi  variable before onCreate method or top of class and remove final keyword from wifi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make your `wifi` variable final. The exception message is self explanatory. This is because you are probably using an inner class or an anonymous constructor for a Listener.

**EDIT**

The comment provided by *imran khan* will also do the trick. It depends what you think is best for your case.

Answer (score 0):

Create function with forward and backward slash. Forward slash for new function and backward slash for devision  equation.

Comment: Only with numbers should the forward and backward slash be used.